# Divider between RadioButtons in RadioGroup - similar to GMail's

Tags: android, radio-button, navigation-drawer, radio-group

In my application, I want to do something similar to what GMail does to manage multiple e-mail accounts. Here is an image of what I want:

[image: GMail's multiple e-mails solution]

I do not know if the GMail app developers used a RadioGroup, but that seems the most elegant solution, so I don't have to manually handle selections, as only one `RadioButton` should be selected at any time. I have tried using the XML tag for `android:divider` and `android:showDividers`, but I was not succesful.

Comment: I think it's a ListView, not a RadioGroup.

Comment: @Vyger and they handle the selection/deselection manually?

Comment: No... don't you know you can have RadioButtons in a ListView?

Comment: @Vyger I knew you could, but I think you still have to handle each one of them individually. Could you provide any examples/code snippets?

Comment: It's a 5 secs Google search.... anyway, look at [here](http://www.roman10.net/android-tutorialcustomized-radio-button-list/)

Comment: @Vyger Thanks! You can answer the question and I'll mark it as answered if you want to :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a ListView, not a RadioGroup.
You can have RadioButtons in a ListView.
[Here](http://www.roman10.net/android-tutorialcustomized-radio-button-list/) is an example.